Big Query Regex Extract
Given String in Column as below:
select * FROM a.b.c x_tbl 
JOIN d.e.f y_tbl on x_tbl.id = y_tbl.id
JOIN g  on x_tbl.id = g.id

We need to extract Words after FROM and JOIN Clauses.
Example Output:
a.b.c, d.e.f, g

Have tried Like below, but it extracts only first occurrences of all words (with Dots) after 'FROM' clause in a string:
  SELECT array_to_string(regexp_extract_all(upper(<col_name>), r'\bFROM\s+[^ ]+',', ') FROM <table_name> LIMIT 10;


Looks like you're only checking against FROM, you'd want to check (?:FROM|JOIN) (not sure if that syntax for a non-capturing group is correct in this regex implementation)

Do you have some sample data that we can use as an example?

Try this
(?<=(FROM|JOIN)\s+)(.*?)\s
Explanation:
FROM or JOIN: (FROM|JOIN)
(FROM|JOIN) followed by one or many spaces: (FROM|JOIN)\s+
Capture a pattern which is preceded by (FROM|JOIN)\s+: (?<=(FROM|JOIN)\s+)
the pattern in question is any character zero or many times: .*
but not greedy .*?: i.e. until the first space character: (.*?)\s
